# jQuery selector which matches the exact value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a `td` which contains a variable so what I do now is this:

```
$('td:contains('+ splitDate[0] + ')').empty().append(
    '<div class="ex-half-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] +'</div>'
);
```

But in this example `splitDate[0]` is "1" so now it selects every `td` which contains a "1".

But what I would like to do if it matches the exact value of `splitDate[0]` than `append` the `<div class="ex-half-done ex-base">`

How can I do this? I already found something like jQuery's `filter()` like this:

```
var $results = $('td').find(splitDate[0]).filter(function()
    return $(this).text() === splitDate[0];
});
console.log('result', $results);

$results.css('color', 'red');
$results.empty().append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] +'</div>');
```

But this returns me every single `td`.

This is an example of a `td` element:

```
<td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c">
  <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->2 </td>
```

Here the picture [image]

And an example of `console.log('check', splitDate[0]) = check 1`

Comment: can you post your `<td>`html?

Comment: I think [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) matches selectors, does `$('td').find('*:contains(' + splitDate[0] + ')').filter(...);` make the filter work as expected?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to iterate over each and compare the strings directly?

Comment: So basically you have `$('td').find('1').filter(...` which you'd think didn't return anything at all, not all the elements ?

Comment: Would it be possible to stick that `2` or whatever you generate there in a span or something?  It could increase the ease at which the problem is tackled.

Comment: @Taplar no it is generated out a calendar component: http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/mobile/ionic-2-calendar

Comment: @Sreinieren have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var $results;
$('td').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == splitDate[0]){
    $results = $(this);
  }
});
console.log('result', $results);
$results.css('color', 'red');
$results.empty().append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] +'</div>');
```

This will ensure that it is an exact match.

Or a little less code:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == splitDate[0]){
    $(this).empty().css('color', 'red').append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] +'</div>');
  }
});
```

[image] **WOULD YOU LIKE TO KNOW [MORE](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.each/)?**

**Update**

Based on your *example* I have a working example to share:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ugrw8hjb/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c"> 1 </td>
    <td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c"> 2 </td>
    <td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c"> 3 </td>
    <td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c"> 4 </td>
    <td _ngcontent-c1="" tappable="" class="monthview-selected monthview-current" ng-reflect-ng-class="monthview-selected monthview-c"> 5 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var splitDate = [2, 1, 2017];
$(function() {
  $('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == splitDate[0].toString()) {
      $(this).empty().css('color', 'red').append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] + '</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Since the content is something like " 2 ", you may want to use `.trim()` to remove whitespace. This will help ensure that "2" == "2", cause " 2 " != "2". Also, based on your other update, it appears you have an array of integers. You will want to use `.toString()` to help compare string to string.

Comment: Tried both of your code, but with the first it returns me `undefined` and the second it doesn't come in the `if statement` because I have some angular 2 bindings within.. like this: `            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->
            1`

Comment: Please provide an example value for `splitDate[0]` or provide example HTML output.

Comment: I changed my question with an example of HTML output

Comment: @Sreinieren that's a pretty poor example. So is the value "2" or "2 "?

Comment: "
            2
        " This is exactly what I copied out of my google inspect

Comment: Ok, @Sreinieren and what is an example of `splitDate`?

Comment: Made some changes in my question hope this is what you where looking for

Comment: Better. So you have something like " 2 ", and then you have an integer `2`, which is very different than a string: `"2"`. Will update my answer.

Comment: maybe you could help me out on this too, I only want to append that div in the `$('.swiper-slide-active')`

Comment: @Sreinieren I suspect I could, but I would advise seeking a similar answer or posting a new question.

Comment: here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318602/jquery-append-div-in-specific-selector-and-get-the-first-one