# Append div in specific selector and get the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calendar where I select a date matches an `array` value and than `append` a `div` to it with some styling. But the problem now is that when the day = 1 it will also select the day 1 form next month because this is also in my `active slider`

Here is a picture of what I mean:
[image]

So basically what I want to do is try to select the first one in my `activer-slider` here is the code how I append the styling to that specific day:

```
$('.swiper-slide-active').find('td').each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).text().trim() == splitDate[0].toString()) {
         $(this).first().empty().append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] + '</div>');
    }
 })
```

So as you see is what I tried to select the first one with the `first()` method but this will change nothing.

Comment: Please stop adding tags to your question titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running your code on all `td` elements, filter them first.

```js
$('.swiper-slide-active td:not(.text-muted)')
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == splitDate[0].toString();
  })
  .empty()
  .append('<div class="ex-done ex-base">' + splitDate[0] + '</div>');
```

---

but keep in mind that you will get the opposite problem when you select the 30th. It will highlight the 30th of the previous month.

So, noticing that the previous/next dates are of different color, i would assume they have a different class, and you should probably use that to identify the current-month dates to filter.

Comment: Yes they have the class: `text-muted` so how would you do that?

Comment: @Sreinieren updated answer (*the selector and also removed the `.first()` since numbers are unique now*)